# File can be decrypted with GPG on the command-line but not by Kleopatra GUI

Tags: gpg4win

A number of encrypted files we receive cannot be decrypted by the Kleopatra GUI but they can be decrypted on the command-line with GPG. Is this a known problem and is there a fix for it?

This is on Windows 10 x64 and the error messages are as follows:

> Decryption failed: Decryption failed.

And in the diagnostics:

```
 gpg: used key is not marked for encryption use. 
 gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected 
 gpg:  decryption forced to fail!
```

The versions are:

```
GnuPG 2.3.4
Libgcrypt 1.9.4
Gpg4win 4.0.0
```

Comment: What operating system? What version? What error messages? Please [edit] the question and don't answer in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been a long time since you posted but I faced the same issue.
the fix is to decrypt the file using the console with the --ignore-mdc-error argument.

```
gpg -d --ignore-mdc-error -o <outputfile> <file_to_decrypt>
```

The error appears on the encryption side, a bad usage of the key, you could see more in this reddit post
https://www.reddit.com/r/pgp/comments/9h7h6h/hintsideas_about_decryption_error/

Hope it helps